# Error 11000 in Mongo Java, DuplicateKeyException

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I have a piece of code, as following and have been getting this error in Java. `coll` is the collection where I need to insert data. I was hoping mongodb would automatically generate the ids so putting the same data (in a for loop) wouldn't matter but I get that error. What should I do?

```
     //   String json1 = XML.toJSONObject(xml_text).toString();
     //   DBObject dbo = (DBObject) com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(json1);
     //   List<DBObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
     //   list.add(dbo);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
            coll.insert(list);
        }
```

`db.collection.getIndexes` returns

```
switched to db ice
> db.next.getIndexes()
[
    {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "ice.next"
    }
]
>
```

Comment: are you trying to insert same data with different _id into the db?

Comment: I am just inserting the same data, and expecting mongodb to use a different id for each time i do that, yes.

Comment: I think you might have specified that the coll's data which you are inserting is unique in schema so this throws an duplicate entry code as 11000

Comment: What should i do to still use the autogenerated _ids?

Comment: Can you try getting rid of `_id` in your `list` object and then insert the object if mongo generates a new id for it everytime.

Comment: I think this is discussing the same issue, but how do i do this in java? https://dzone.com/articles/mongocursorexception-e11000 @nullpointer

Comment: Using Mongo shell could you run `db.collection.getIndexes()` and add the response to your question. Your `coll` must have a unique index which your inserts are breaching.

Comment: Added that to the question . It just returns `[]`
@glitch

Comment: @glitch I just checked I had been running the command on the wrong db, that command actually returns this:

switched to db ice
> db.next.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "ice.next"
        }
]
>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. I was using the same DBObject in the loop, hence the error. Creating one inside the loop now, no issues. Thanks everyone.